# How fast we can change direction of rotation of a stepper motor

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, bidirectional

I want to do the following of a stepper motor with following characteristics which has 100 RPM

1. change DOR(direction of rotation) every alternative rotation in the opposite direction
2. control the speed of change
3. control the angle of rotation i.e 30 degrees or 40 degrees after which it will change the DOR
4. Ability to lock at any position

this is to try flapping wing orinthopter we cannot control wing beat angle and to implement gliding with current idea of using normal DC motor with crank mechanisms because we cant determine the mid point of wing beat.

can we do this?

Comment: Yes. Care to refine your question?

Comment: If you have no mass on the rotor of the motor, you can change direction after each step without issues. Anything else is going to require considerably more detail of your implementation.

Comment: To give you an idea this is to try flapping wing orinthocopter,where I want to try this. Number 3 mentioned in the wing beat angle.The speed is controlled either by throttle or by altitude (autopilot). So if if the difference in current altitude and target altitude is too big it will flap to wide angle and faster,else low angle slower. any ideas please?

Comment: If the step angle is critical use an "encoder" with a "DC motor". Control the rate of acceleration/deceleration as there is mass involved. Such as in opening a combination lock.

Comment: The DC motor concept cannot work because of other design restrictions such as we cannot glide as explained,it is possible with addition of hard wares eg:sensors which increases weight. that is why i want to try this way

Comment: Do you understand that servos are DC motors with feedback? It sounds like you need a servo rather than a stepper.

Comment: I would think that the flapping would be instantiated by a motor working in one direction to drive something like a cam.

Answer (score 1):

We can't tell whether you can do this since we don't know what your capabilities are, obviously.

A stepper motor can be reversed, of course.  The question is how fast, considering how hard you are driving it and how much effective inertia an other forces are at its shaft.  A stepper motor has a maximum speed it can be run at for a given drive level and still stay in lock.  That speed goes down the higher the force it has to produce.  Reversing direction is not different than taking any other step, except that the speed and mass of whatever is connected to the motor will apply a apposing force, so the speed you can reverse at will be much lower than the normal operating speed.

This applies to any accelleration or decelleration.  Reversing isn't special just because it happens to change the sign of the speed.

Comment: The AUW(All up weight) is 10 Kg and wing span of 2 Meters and chord of 30 cm is what I thought of and powering with two Steppers or BLDC or Servo motors.What ever is feasible to implement my concept of flapping wings with adjustable angle of attack. throttle movement effects angle of attack + flapping speed depending on flight environment.my capabilities limited to concepts.any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My intuition tells me you will not get enough power out of a stepper to lift its own weight.  I could be wrong.  RC guys tend to favor brush less motors.  You would need a position sensor and feedback.  Probably best to run the motor at high rpm and gear down.  Unfortunately the above will have pretty high inertia and will be hard to modulate the speed/direction quickly.  I would run some calculations about power, torque, weight, and required rate of change in speed to see if what you are trying is feasible even with a real motor and an imagined control circuit.  If you are reversing every cycle, perhaps a mechanical linkage would do the job.